# T-SQL How to get Week Number (ISO) of First Week from all Quarters from GetDate()?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, date

The title says it pritty much.

But to be more precise, I need to get the Week Number of each week first starting in Quarters 1-4 from any given year from GetDate().

Not sure if this is something that's built in or I have to write a function for.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's customary to give it a crack first and then ask for comment on your approach/technique.

Comment: Which definition of "quarter" are you using? Does quarter 1 start with week 1, or does it start with Jan 1?

Comment: @Fellmeister, sorry I haven't tried anything yet... am doing it now though... reason I posted here is because I'm in a bit of a rush :-(

Comment: @hvd here the quarter starts on 1st of Jan, Apr, Jul, Oct

Comment: You ask "the Week Number of each week first starting in Quarters 1-4" but already accepted an answer which instead gives you the week numbers in which quarters 1-4 start. Those are close but not the same thing. Are you sure you're getting the numbers you're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple, but does the trick.  You would set `@date` to any given value.  I used `getdate()`.

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()

declare @year int = datepart(year, @date)

select @year as [year]
      ,datepart(iso_week, cast('1/1/'  + cast(@year as char(4)) as date)) as ISOWeekQ1
      ,datepart(iso_week, cast('4/1/'  + cast(@year as char(4)) as date)) as ISOWeekQ2
      ,datepart(iso_week, cast('7/1/'  + cast(@year as char(4)) as date)) as ISOWeekQ3
      ,datepart(iso_week, cast('10/1/' + cast(@year as char(4)) as date)) as ISOWeekQ4
```

For me, this returned:

```
year        ISOWeekQ1   ISOWeekQ2   ISOWeekQ3   ISOWeekQ4
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2017        52          13          26          39
```

This also works, and doesn't use `cast()` or risk date conversion errors for different formats of the date (e.g., yyyy/mm/dd):

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()

set @date = dateadd(day, - datepart(dayofyear, @date) + 1, @date) -- sets date to Jan 1

select datepart(year, @date) [year]
      ,datepart(iso_week, @date) as ISOWeekQ1
      ,datepart(iso_week, dateadd(month, 3, @date)) as ISOWeekQ2
      ,datepart(iso_week, dateadd(month, 6, @date)) as ISOWeekQ3
      ,datepart(iso_week, dateadd(month, 9, @date)) as ISOWeekQ4
```

The output of this query is the same as the first.

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2012+, you could use `datepart(iso_week, datefromparts(@year,1,1)) as ISOWeekQ1, [...]` or `datepart(iso_week, datefromparts(year(getdate()),1,1)) as ISOWeekQ1, [...]`.  That's slightly more elegant.